# I want to figure out a sql statement for a complex data structure

Tags: sql

I am working on trying to access data from a table by using joins. I am given information for a primary key in A and want to retrieve information from X. There are two ways to get to X, one by going through B and one by going through C. Which path I choose is decided from a column in A. I tried to create a sql statement that uses CASE WHEN and joins the tables with a FROM statement in this manner:

X - Join - B - Right Outer Join - A - Left Outer Join - C - Join - X

but sql tells me I can't join the same table at both ends. I use outer join because A will either have a connection to B or C, but not both.

Basically, I need to retrieve data from X, but X is accessed using different keys depending on which path is deemed in a column in A.

Comment: What have you tried (actual code if possible), and what database are you using. Syntax varies from db to db.

Comment: This sounds like a fairly appropriate use of a stored procedure. Is there a requirement that you use a single select rather than a sproc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a query like this:

```
SELECT X.* 
FROM A 
LEFT JOIN B ON B.A_id = A.id 
LEFT JOIN C ON C.A_id = A.id 
LEFT JOIN X ON X.id = IF(A.path = 'B', B.X_id, C.X_id) 
WHERE A.id = <numeric_id>;
```

I tested this query on MySQL with these data:

Table A:

```
 ------ ------
| id   | path |
 ------ ------
|    1 | B    |
|    2 | B    |
|    3 | C    |
|    4 | C    |
 ------ ------
```

Table B:

```
 ------ ------
| A_id | X_id |
 ------ ------
|    1 |    9 |
|    2 |    8 |
 ------ ------
```

Table C:

```
 ------ ------
| A_id | X_id |
 ------ ------
|    3 |    7 |
|    4 |    6 |
 ------ ------
```

Table X:

```
 ------ -------
| id   | value |
 ------ -------
|    1 |    10 |
|    2 |    20 |
|    3 |    30 |
|    4 |    40 |
|    5 |    50 |
|    6 |    60 |
|    7 |    70 |
|    8 |    80 |
|    9 |    90 |
 ------ -------
```

If you remove the WHERE clause and SELECT A.id, B.X_id, C.X_id, X.* you'll have the following result, which confirms what table is the actual path to X:

```
 -------- -------- -------- -------- --------- 
| A.id   | B.X_id | C.X_id | X.id   | X.value |
 ------ ------ ------ ------ ------- ---------
|      1 |      9 |   NULL |      9 |      90 |
|      2 |      8 |   NULL |      8 |      80 |
|      3 |   NULL |      7 |      7 |      70 |
|      4 |   NULL |      6 |      6 |      60 |
 -------- -------- -------- -------- ---------
```

Hope it works for you!

Answer (score 0):

This is doable if you choose *both* paths like this:

```
SELECT ....
FROM A

LEFT JOIN B ON A.bkey = B.bkey
LEFT JOIN X as XB ON B.xkey = XB.xkey

LEFT JOIN C ON A.ckey = C.ckey
LEFT JOIN X as XC ON C.xkey = XC.xkey
```

And then if you just want (for example) field 1 out of X, then you might use a function like:

```
SELECT ISNULL(XB.field1, XC.field1)...
```

Or some such

Answer (score 0):

You could also do a UNION or UNION ALL query (if teh two tables are mutuially exclusive)

```
Select a.field1, b.field2
from tableA a
join tableb b on a.table1id - b.table1id
Union all
Select a.field1, c.field2
from tableA a
join tablec c on a.table1id - c.table1id
```